# Why i'm getting the following error? ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

Here is the code

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard

# Condição de partida da máquina
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ENTER'):
        print('\nProcessando...\n')
        sleep(2)
        break

print('\nRETIRE O CARTÃO.')

opcao = int(input('SELECIONE UMA OPÇÃO:\n'
                  '\033[32m[1] DEPÓSITO\033[m\n'
                  '\033[32m[2] SAQUE\033[m\n'
                  '\033[32m[3] SALDO/EXTRATO\033[m\n'
                  '\033[32m[4] POUPANÇA\033[m\n'))
```

and now, the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-", line 18, in <module>
    opcao = int(input('SELECIONE UMA OPÇÃO:\n'
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I can't find what's wrong with the code... Someone can help me?
I've already tried to rewrite the code, but this problem is really killing me...

Comment: `input` returned an empty string. This will happen if you just press return without entering anything else before.

Comment: Remove the `int(...)` cast and print out just the value that `input(...)` returns. It probably isn't a number.

Comment: @Matthias the problem is: I'm not pressing anything, the error comes automatically

Comment: @notoriousjere i can't press any key, the error comes automatically...

Answer (score 0):

Probably as input you entered string value which can't be casted to int type(in your case empty string - you pressed `Enter`), it only accepts number like 1,2,10,15,-1, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i've only changed the arg:

```
keyboard.is_pressed
```

to

```
keyboard.read_key
```